# Python recognize_google from speech recognition module fails when run without console

Tags: python, console, speech-recognition, pyinstaller, speech-to-text

When run with console, module works fine without errors but using Pyinstaller to convert it to consoleless executables makes my program crash. It works till `recognize_google()` function. This is the full code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import autopy3
import ctypes
import winsound
from winsound import *

upali = sr.Recognizer()

def slusaj():
print("Cekam naredbu...")
with sr.Microphone() as glas:
    zvuk = upali.listen(glas)
    winsound.Beep(670,400)
try:    
    #naredba = upali.recognize_google(zvuk)
    winsound.Beep(270,400)
except:
    slusaj()

#try:
winsound.Beep(870,400)
    #naredba = upali.recognize_google(zvuk)
print("Rekao si: "+ upali.recognize_google(zvuk))
winsound.Beep(1000,800)
    #if naredba == "Lock" or "lock":
    #   ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
if upali.recognize_google(zvuk) == "lock":
        #winsound.Beep(670,400)
    ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
else:
        slusaj()
#except:
    #slusaj()

slusaj()
```

Comment: What is the crash? Post the traceback.

Comment: that's the problem, i cannot see since it only crashes when there is no console, it works in pythonwin and idle. If it helps, it first freezes and then crashes later